# How to publish a previous version of an item in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I want my authors to be able to publish a new version of an item and then later roll back to an older version of the item. How would one make a previous version of an item the latest?

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of ways (I think) editors can do this.

1. Use publishing restrictions (Publish ribbon > Restrictions > Change) to mark the latest version of an item as not 'Publishable'. When the item is published, the last 'Publishable' version will replace the latest.
2. If workflow is in place, when an editor reverts the latest version of an item to 'Draft', the previous version would be the one that would get published.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Another option when workflow is in place, is to select the previous version (or the version you want live) in the Content Editor, then click 'add version' in the Version tab. This will make a copy of the selected version (instead of the latest version).

Answer (score 0):

In our setup, we cannot simply roll back to a needed version easily. Selecting a previous version and clicking 'Save' does not do anything. But we use a trick:
- Click Version tab, Click Versions - select a previous version you want to restore
- Then after it loads, click Versions - Add new version. Save it.
Now a copy of an old version is the 'latest' which you can Publish.